# Why is the 'Be The Zombie Mode' DLC for Dying Light not free?

Tags: ps4, dying-light

I want to play as a zombie in Dying Light on my PS4, I bought the game in November. I searched the Internet on how to invade another player's game and they say to download the free DLC, but in the PlayStation Store, it's not free. I have PlayStation Plus.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What region are you in? In the UK store it's still free.

Comment: Singapore @Kodama

Comment: I couldn't find any announcement or explanation for why it isn't free in Singapore, but the DLC only seems to be free outside of Asia. It's free in the US and European stores, but not in all Asian stores where I could find it (like Hong Kong and Thailand). It looks like you'll have to pay for it in Asia.

Comment: That's disappointing when they say it is free in the main menu then you have to pay for it. I will try to ask in the forum of Dying Light instead. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the Be The Zombie mode only costs money if you download The Following from the console store. If you don't want to have to pay, you can go to your nearest GameStop or other large chained video game selling store and buy The Following on disc, which comes with Be The Zombie and Bozak's Challenge.